# Stop all sounds Soundcloud

Tags: jquery, soundcloud

I've built a small gallery using Anything Slider + Soundcloud . You can see it here: www.diasporaduo.com  (multimedia section). The problem is that, when I hide the "mp3content" div, I have no way to stop the background sound. So far my code looks like this:

```
$('#mp3content').hide();


$('#mp3').click(function(){
$('#mp3content').fadeIn('slow');
});

$('#mp3close').click(function(){
$('#mp3content').fadeOut('slow'); 
});
```

This code simply shows/hide the div "mp3content", containing a slider with all the playlists.

Answer (score 1):

How are you embedding the sound? If you're using the Widget, you could use the [Widget API](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget) to control playback. Otherwise, you could consider using the [Javascript SDK](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#javascript).

Answer (score 0):

You may pause the sound cloud player like this

```
$('.sc-player.playing a.sc-pause').click();
```

Comment: Thanks but no luck. I inserted your code in my $('#mp3close').click(function(){}  function and it doesn't do anything. Where are you supposed to insert your code? I need to trigger the pause function when the user clicks on the "mp3close" div.

Comment: Hi.I think you want to trigger a pause function and you are using the SC object, you need to catch the 'streamer' instance in an outer function variable. then, you can invoke a play/pause using the built-in ".is_playing" SC object method:

`var streamer;
function streamTrack(uri) {

    SC.stream(uri)
        .then(function (player) {
            if (!streamer){
                streamer = player;
            }
                if (streamer._isPlaying === true){
                streamer.pause();
            } else {
                streamer.play();
            }
        })
}
`